# scala regex to limit with double space

Tags: regex, scala

I have a data like below

```
135 stjosephhrsecschool             london  DunAve
175865 stbele_higher_secondary sch  New York     
11 st marys high school for women   Paris  Louis Avenue
```

I want to extract id schoolname city  area.

Pattern is id(digits) followed by single space then school name. name can have multiple words split by single space or it may have special chars. then minimum of double space or more then city . Again city may have multi words split space or may have special chars. then minimum of 2 spaces or more then its area. Even area follows the same properties as school name & city. But area may or may not present in the line. If its not then i want null value for area.

Here is regex I have tried.

```
([\d]+) ([\w\s\S]+)\s\s+([\w\s\S]+)\s\s+([\w\s\S]*)
```

But This regex is not stopping when it see more than 2 spaces. Not sure how to modify this to fit to my data.

all the help are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You input is not in good shape: city names must be capitalized. If the IDs (I guess, the second capturing group matches them) are always lowercase, and cities *were* capitalized, it would be easy to match these strings. However, I think you are stuck if your input is like what you showed.

Comment: Assuming normal spaces as separators, you could use [`^(\d+) (\S+(?: \S+)*) {2,}(\S+(?: \S+)*) {2,}(\S+(?: \S+)*)? *$`](https://regex101.com/r/BGQF4r/1) or you just split on double spaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly - the issue is that the resulting groups contain trailing spaces (e.g. `"Louis Avenue "`). If so - you can fix this by using the *non-greedy* modifiers like `+?` and `*?`:

```
([\d]+) ([\w\s\S]+?)\s\s+([\w\s\S]+?)\s\s+([\w\s\S]*?)?\s*
```

Which results in what seems to be the desired output:

```
val s1 = "135 stjosephhrsecschool             london  DunAve"
val s2 = "175865 stbele_higher_secondary sch  New York     "
val s3 = "11 st marys high school for women   Paris  Louis Avenue "

val r = """([\d]+) ([\w\s\S]+?)\s\s+([\w\s\S]+?)\s\s+([\w\s\S]*?)?\s*""".r

def matching(s: String) = s match {
  case r(a,b,c,d) => println((a,b,c,d))
  case _ => println("no match")
}

matching(s1) // (135,stjosephhrsecschool,london,DunAve)
matching(s2) // (175865,stbele_higher_secondary sch,New York,)
matching(s3) // (11,st marys high school for women,Paris,Louis Avenue)
```

Comment: Thanks Tzach Zohar . This gives exactly what i need. I am going to learn about this non greedy operators now. Had always limited my self to \w,\s\S\d\D\W alone.May they were just basics . Thank you very much.